# Deselect selected options when tapped(selected) on last option in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, swift2

Need a little help from you, I am working on Table View where I have an Array which is received from server. The Array is nothing but Multiple Choice Options. It looks something like this

a. Table

b. Bottle

c. Hat

d. Bucket

e. None of the Above.

What I Want ?
I want to select multiple answers i.e Table , Bottle , Bucket and it is shown by checkbox marked. Which I have managed to do it well. And when last option i.e None of the Above is selected I want to deselect all the above checked mark options and just show the None option checked, even this is working.

Where I am stuck?
When "None of the Above" is in selected mode and I tap on any other option then "None" should be deselected. This is not working , I don't know whats wrong here. Please help. TIA

Here's my didSelect Method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
        if selectedString == "None of the above" {

             selectedIndex = indexPath.row

             self.isNoneSelected = true

             for  index  in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! 

         {
             tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true)
         }

}
```

And my None option will always be at last position, so even array.lastobject will work I guess

Comment: We need to see the code that fires when you tap "none of the above".

Comment: Sure , will update the question @MauryMarkowitz

Comment: update your code , what you have tried so far if possible

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari please have a look at my question I have updated it with code snippet

Comment: it should be **"None of the Above"** as per question ,in place of  **"None of the above"** a is small chk uppercase is it ?

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Its working snippet, its proper in code , "a" is small. I need to deselect my last option i.e "None of the above" when i select any other option for eg. Hat. hope you get my query. And I also asked in the last line that my none option will always be last hence any alternative method to check it rather than checking via String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it too complicated here. All you need is an array of boolean to store the selected states, and **reloadData()** for the tableView, if you add an UIImageView to represent selected state.
It's not a good idea to call tableView.deselectRow() for every row directly

```
var selected = Array(repeating: false, count: 5)

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
//let cell = whatever
   cell.checkMark.isHidden = !selected[indexPath.row]
//return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    selected[indexPath.row] = !selected[indexPath.row]

    if (indexPath.row == selected.count - 1 ) {//if 'None' is selected
        for i in 0..<selected.count-2 {
            selected[i] = false
        }
    } else { //all other rows will deselect the 'None' row
        selected[selected.count - 1 ] = false
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can't be sure, but it looks like this code handles all selection events, right? If so, there appear to be several problems:

1) `selectedIndex` is only set if they select the last item. I suspect that is not what you want, but I cannot be sure.

2) same for `self.isNoneSelected = true` - I suspect you want to use this value in other methods to see if that is the selected item, but you don't seem to have any code to turn it off again.

3) you turn off the selection for all the other items, but don't turn on selection for "none" - but that might have already happened in the event, I don't see the rest of the code there.

So I think you want something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndex = indexPath.row
    if selectedString == "None of the above" {
         self.isNoneSelected = true
         for  index  in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows! 
         {
             tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: true)
         }
   } else {
         self.isNoneSelected = false
//NOTE I AM NOT AT MY MACHINE SO I DON'T KNOW THE EXACT SYNTAX HERE
//THE IDEA IS TO GET THE INDEX PATH OF THE LAST ITEM SO WE CAN TURN IT OFF
         tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.indexPathForRow(mydatasource.count-1, inSection:0), animated: true)
    }
}
```